# std::mutex Initialisation Exception

Tags: c++, c++11

When I run the following, I get an exception: `Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)` and the program crashes.

```
#include <mutex>

class MutexTest
{
public:
    static std::mutex GlobalMutex;
};

std::mutex MutexTest::GlobalMutex;


int main()
{
    MutexTest test;
    test.GlobalMutex.unlock(); //makes it throw.
    return 0;
}
```

But if I do:

```
int main()
{
    StaticMutexTest test;
    test.GlobalMutex.lock();
    test.GlobalMutex.unlock();
    test.GlobalMutex.unlock();
    test.GlobalMutex.unlock();
    return 0;
}
```

it runs just fine. How can I initialise the mutex other than having to lock it first? I read somewhere that `0xC0000005` means the variable is not initialised. The documentation says the mutex must be locked first before it can be unlocked and that unlocking on an unlocked mutex is undefined behaviour. But there's nothing for me to test whether it is locked yet.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your mutex is initalized, there's no problem here other than the fact you cannot unlock() a mutex that your thread havn't already locked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`unlock()`ing a `std::mutex` which isn't `lock()`ed by the thread calling `unlock()` is undefined behavior. The `std::mutex` will always be initially unlocked. If you want to create a mutex which is initially locked, you'll need a wrapper which does the locking. I can't imagine what the use of such a device would be, though.

Comment: Ahh but the thing is, there is no way for me to check if it is locked by the current thread already. Doing try_lock is undefined behaviour. Am I stuck then?

Comment: @using try_lock() is not undefined, but you normally shouldn't need to check if the mutex is locked. You know when you lock the mutex (since you wrote the code to do so), so you should also know when to unlock it.

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames: If you don't know if a thread owns a lock of not, there is something deeper wrong in your design still! There are very few reasons where mutex locks are not held locally and are managed by a suitable RAII class, e.g., `std::lock_guard<Mutex>` or `std::unique_lock<Mutex>`.

Comment: @nos: actually according to 30.4.1.2 [thread.mutex.requirements.mutex] paragraph 15, you can't `try_lock()` a `std::mutex` already owned by a thread: "Requires:If m is of type `std::mutex` or `std::timed_mutex`, the calling thread does not own the mutex"

Comment: Ah ok. I will redo my design. I'll accept your answer as soon as it lets me. My design was a class that holds a list of mutexes in a map. Then in the destructor I was iterating all of them, unlocking and clearing the map. I'll figure out a different way.